# Override `show-trailing-whitespace` in `diff-mode`

Tags: diff-mode, whitespace

I have `show-trailing-whitespace` set to `t` globally in my `.emacs` file, and this is generally not a problem except for when I'm in `diff-mode` looking at a patch which has mandatory trailing white space for blank context lines.

One solution would be to simply turn off `show-trailing-whitespace` in `diff-mode` in some relevant hook, but actually I'd like for trailing white space in change lines to still show up. For example, if I've accidentally introduced trailing white space or if I'm removing it, that's ok, and **I still want that to show up in the `trailing-whitespace` face**. I just don't want the blank context lines to be treated as trailing white space since they are necessary for the diff format itself.

Here's an example of the current behavior that I get:

[image]

And this is what I would like:

[image]

Here's another example, but this time, with *actual* whitespace addition:

[image]

However if I disable `show-trailing-whitespace` entirely in `diff-mode`, then I wouldn't see any dark red at all. Instead, this is what I'm wanting:

[image]

Basically, I think this involves making `show-trailing-whitespace` aware that diff lines with just a single space are special.

Comment: Are you sure just disabling this entirely in diff-mode is not what you want? If you've added or removed trailing whitespace accidentally, won't diff-mode highlight that regardless of your emacs configuration (by virtue of the fact that it's a change in the file)?

Comment: I want to see the trailing whitespace in the white space font of red. Feel free to include an answer for disabling just in diff-mode as that might be helpful for other people, but that's not exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Would it be satisfactory if diff-mode's own highlighting face was set to something similar to white-space-mode's red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to turn off Trailing whitespace mode in Diff mode, and instead define your own custom font lock rules for the trailing whitespace that you don't want to see.

```
(defvar diff-trailing-whitespace-keywords
  '(("^[+-<>]\\(.*\\S \\)?\\(\\s +\\)$" (2 'trailing-whitespace t))))
(defun diff-mode-font-lock-add-trailing-whitespace ()
  (setq diff-font-lock-keywords-and-whitespace
    (append diff-font-lock-keywords
        diff-trailing-whitespace-keywords))
  (setcar diff-font-lock-defaults 'diff-font-lock-keywords-and-whitespace))
(defun turn-off-trailing-whitespace ()
  (setq show-trailing-whitespace nil))
(add-hook 'diff-mode-hook 'turn-off-trailing-whitespace)
(eval-after-load "diff-mode" '(diff-mode-font-lock-add-trailing-whitespace))
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of `show-trailing-whitespace` becomes buffer local when set so you can just set it in the relevant hook:

```
(add-hook 'diff-mode-hook (lambda () (setq show-trailing-whitespace nil)))
```

To check the documentation for show-trailing-whitespace: `C-h v show-trailing-whitespace`.

Comment: But that turns off the mode for the whole buffer, which is precisely what b4hand wants to avoid.